# Find and replace text in a text file

Tags: vb.net, replace

I am creating a program that finds a specific sentence in a word path and replaces it with a given value.

Specific sentence: `l="600"`

And it has to be changed to : `l="300"`

This is not to difficult and works fine:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Property sign As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim sign1 As String
Dim sign2 As String


sign1 = ("""600""") 'original value
sign2 = ("""300""") 'New value

Dim source As String = "C:\temp\bodem.mpr" 'path from original file
Dim destination As String = "C:\temp\bodem2.mpr" 'path new file
Dim oldText As String = "l=" & sign1 'old value
Dim newText As String = "l=" & sign2 'new value

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(destination, My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText (source).Replace(oldText, newText), False)
Process.Start("C:\temp\bodem2.mpr") 'opens program in wordpath to control value
End Sub 

End Class
```

The only problem is that the original sentence : `l="600"` does not always have the value 600, but instead always has a different value that I don't know. (Example : l="600" / l="600.02" / l="300" / l="1600.02")  How can I write this down in my code.

Comment: Dim sign1 As String
 Dim sign2 As String

 sign1 = ("""600""")
 sign2 = ("""300""")

 Dim source As String = "C:\temp\bodem.mpr" 'path from original file
 Dim destination As String = "C:\temp\bodem2.mpr" 'path new file
 Dim oldText As String = "l=" & sign1 'old value
 Dim newText As String = "l=" & sign2 'new value

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(destination, My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(source).Replace(oldText, newText), False)
Process.Start("C:\temp\bodem2.mpr") 'opens program in wordpath to control value
End Sub

Comment: You should modify the code block to make it more readable (i.e. remove line numbers, fix indentation) and add a tag for what language you're using.

Comment: You can use regex to replace the text / decimals.

Comment: We can see that, you can use `RegEx` (regular expressions) **in** VB.NET